# WPF Toolkit Accordion Control Expand/Collapse

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I want to use the Accordion Control that comes with the WPF Toolkit.

There are two things I wasn't able to archive:

1. I need an Eventhandler that fires when a Accordion Item get Expanded/Collapsed
2. I need to Set the Expanded Status of an Accordion Item in Code behind.

Are this things even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The regular System.Windows.Controls Expander (not toolkit) has those features.

[System.Windows.Controls.Expander](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms609881.aspx):

- There is an Expanded Event.
- There is a Collapsed event.
- And there is an IsExpanded property.

If you don't know how to use events, properties, binding, or code behind then those are the things you need to learn.

Comment: The link refers to the Expander not the Accordion from the WPF toolkit.

Comment: @Phil  Yes and maybe he would be better off with Expander if it has the features he is looking for.  For the record I did not down vote you.

Comment: ok, edit the post in some way to mention the expander and I'll remove the down vote.

Comment: It refers to expander not the AccordionItem

Comment: @tortexy Yes that was my intent. "The regular System.Windows.Controls Expander"   It did get marked as the answer.

Comment: In that case it is an incomplete answer.

Comment: @tortexy An incomplete answer marked as the answer.  Interesting combination.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the SelectedItem(s) property of the Accordion should give you all you need.
For 2), just set SelectedItem, respectively add/remove in SelectedItems.
For 1), listen to the SelectedItemsChanged event (SelectedItemChanged respectively).

```
void MyAccordion_SelectedItemsChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
        {
            // item expanded
        }
    }
    if (e.OldItems != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
        {
            // item collapsed
        }
    }
}
```